Show that $f(x)=e^x+x^2+1$
We know that $f$ is differentiable and I have already found that $f(0)=2 $ and $\lim_{h \to 0} \left ( \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h) }{2h} \right)=e^x+2x$  , for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
And I need to show that $f(x)=e^x+x^2+1$
My first thought was to let $φ(x)=f(x)-e^x-x^2-1$
then take the derivative
$$φ'(x)=f'(x) -e^x-2x=f'(x)-(e^x +2x)$$
then I noticed that $e^x + 2x = \lim_{h \to 0} \left ( \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h) }{2h} \right) $ and I am assuming that this limit is $f'(0) $ (maybe I am wrong) , how can I prove that the limit is the derivative of $f$ computed at some point?

I think you're confused about the definition of derivative. The limit is not equal to the derivative at some point--notice you are only taking $h \to 0$, but you are allowing $x$ to be anything. That tells you the limit is a function of $x$, hence the notation $f'(x)$, not $f'(0)$. The problem is actually asking you to show via a variation of the fundamental theorem of calculus, most likely. Have you learned integrals yet?

Oh, I was thinking that maybe with a substitution we would get the derivative of $f$ at some point but I could not figure out what to substitute

I see where your confusion is--that was something I struggled with too. The problem is that you are given a condition about $f(0) = 2$, and that does not tell you anything about $f'(0)$. So working on the derivative is not as useful--in some sense the original function $f$ has "more information" than the derivative. The reason is because when we take the derivative of $f$, any constants in $f$ (the $+1$ in this case) will go away! So the $f(0) = 2$ condition allows you to recover the $+1$ when you "undo" the derivative.

Alright that makes a bit of sense I will try to think of another way then, thank you!

If we are reinventing the wheel.  Note the following: If $f(x)$ is differentiable and $g(x)= f(x) + K$ for some constant then $f'(x) = g'(x)$. More difficult: If $f,g$ are diff. and $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(a)=g(a)$ for some $a$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, or equivalently If $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x$ and $C=g(a)-f(a)$ for some $a$ then $g(x)=f(x) + C$ for all $x$. And $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{-h\to 0^-}\frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}$ so $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$... from that it will all fall out... If you can show all that.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-(f(x-h)}{2h}=f'(x)$$
Since we know that $f'(x)=e^x+2x$ we can integrate this equation:
$$\int f'(x)\,dx=\int (e^x+2x)\,dx\Rightarrow f(x)+c=e^x+x^2$$
By evaluating the equation in $0$ we get $c=1$ hence: $f(x)=e^x+x^2+1$

Rectify your mistake please. c=1. You mistyped it

Two things you need to know.

If $f'(x) = g'(x)$ then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same function only a constant shift apart.  In other words $f(x) -g(x) = C$ or $g(x) =f(x) + C$ for some constant.
$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} =\frac 12\lim\limits_{h\to 0}[\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}]=\frac 12[\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h + \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-(-h))-f(x)}{-h}]=\frac 12[f'(x)+f'(x)] =f'(x)$

From there it's simple:
$f'(x) = e^x + 2x$ and $(e^x + x^2 + 1)' = e^x + 2x$.  So $f(x) = e^x + x^2 + 1 + C$ for some constant $C$.  Which constant?  Well we are told $f(0)=2$ so $f(0)=e^0 + 0^2 + 1 + C = 2$.  So $C = 0$. And $f(x) = e^x + x^2 + 1$.
...
Your strategey of $g(x) = f(x) - e^x -x^2 -1$ would work perfectly:
$g'(x) = f'(x) - e^x-2x = f'(x) - \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}= f'(x) - f'(x) = 0$
So $g(x) = k$ for some constant.  Which constant?  well $g(0) = k = f(0)-e^0 -0^2 -1 = 2-1-0-1=0$.
So $g(x) = k = 0 = f(x) - e^x -x^2 -1$ so $f(x) =e^x +x^2 + 1$.
